# plotly crashing over the globals object contents

Tags: pytest, plotly-python

When I introduce a pytest.ini file comprising the following [content](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/example/pythoncollection.html#customizing-test-collection):

```
[pytest]
python_files = *.py
```

Then I get the following crash:

```
$ python -m pytest a.py 
========================================== test session starts ==========================================
platform linux -- Python 3.9.5, pytest-7.1.0, pluggy-1.0.0 , configfile: pytest.ini
collected 0 items / 1 error                                                                             

================================================ ERRORS =================================================
_________________________________________ ERROR collecting a.py _________________________________________
a.py:1: in <module>
    import plotly.express as px
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1007: in _find_and_load
    ???
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:986: in _find_and_load_unlocked
    ???
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:680: in _load_unlocked
    ???
venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:168: in exec_module
    exec(co, module.__dict__)
venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/plotly/express/__init__.py:15: in <module>
    from ._imshow import imshow
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1007: in _find_and_load
    ???
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:986: in _find_and_load_unlocked
    ???
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:680: in _load_unlocked
    ???
venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:168: in exec_module
    exec(co, module.__dict__)
venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/plotly/express/_imshow.py:3: in <module>
    from ._core import apply_default_cascade, init_figure, configure_animation_controls
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1007: in _find_and_load
    ???
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:986: in _find_and_load_unlocked
    ???
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:680: in _load_unlocked
    ???
venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:168: in exec_module
    exec(co, module.__dict__)
venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/plotly/express/_core.py:8: in <module>
    from plotly.colors import qualitative, sequential
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1007: in _find_and_load
    ???
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:986: in _find_and_load_unlocked
    ???
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:680: in _load_unlocked
    ???
venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:168: in exec_module
    exec(co, module.__dict__)
venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/plotly/colors/__init__.py:16: in <module>
    from _plotly_utils.colors import *  # noqa: F401
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1007: in _find_and_load
    ???
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:986: in _find_and_load_unlocked
    ???
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:680: in _load_unlocked
    ???
venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:168: in exec_module
    exec(co, module.__dict__)
venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/_plotly_utils/colors/__init__.py:89: in <module>
    from . import (  # noqa: F401
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1007: in _find_and_load
    ???
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:986: in _find_and_load_unlocked
    ???
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:680: in _load_unlocked
    ???
venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:168: in exec_module
    exec(co, module.__dict__)
venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/_plotly_utils/colors/qualitative.py:146: in <module>
    from .colorbrewer import Set1, Pastel1, Dark2, Set2, Pastel2, Set3  # noqa: F401
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1007: in _find_and_load
    ???
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:986: in _find_and_load_unlocked
    ???
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:680: in _load_unlocked
    ???
venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:168: in exec_module
    exec(co, module.__dict__)
venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/_plotly_utils/colors/colorbrewer.py:465: in <module>
    globals()[_k + "_r"] = _cols[::-1]
E   TypeError: 'module' object is not subscriptable
======================================== short test summary info ========================================
ERROR a.py - TypeError: 'module' object is not subscriptable
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 error during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
=========================================== 1 error in 0.55s ============================================
```

The following reduced target python file reproduces the error on my setup, when providing it as the target for pytest:

```
import plotly.express as px    
def test_a():
    pass
```

Whereas without the configuration file being present, pytest executes the test normally.

I might guess from the error that some library or path, or a dynamic definition brought in through my above pytest configuration ― either contains or is a module called *globals*, which then overrides python's built-in *globals* object when the test is being run by pytest. I failed to prove that this is indeed the case through several search methods however.

My goal in setting a pytest configuration is to have it collect test functions from all of the project's python files (as we interleave test code at the bottom of class files and not just in files marked as test files).

Comment: Maybe the context makes this unlikely, but if `_cols` were a module when the line is executed, you'd get the same error -- the `[::-1]` type of subscripting produces the same message.

Comment: I see the source at https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/blob/03979d105c65dda3df3a155322eaff18f203b03f/packages/python/plotly/_plotly_utils/colors/colorbrewer.py -- it looks like it assumes _every_ global that doesn't start with `_` or `swatches` or end with `_r` is subscriptable. Seems like a reasonable workaround for the loop that's crashing to actually check for that, e.g. continue if `type(_cols) != list`, not just checking the var name. `pytest` or anything else adding a global is all it takes to crash it now.

Comment: Thanks, got it. I think it's then a matter for discussion at the plotly develoment / issues channels, as I do not possess the confidence to suggest changes to that fiddling of the globals object without being fully aware of its purpose there.

Comment: This is now solved by a recent commit in plotly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As best I can guess, the problem isn't that `globals()` isn't subscriptable, but that `_cols` isn't, because [the source](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/blob/03979d105c65dda3df3a155322eaff18f203b03f/packages/python/plotly/_plotly_utils/colors/colorbrewer.py) shows `_cols` takes the value of every global in the module, and the subscript operation is skipped for a hardcoded set of names.

On the Plotly side they could make this more robust to whatever pytest is doing by checking the type of `_cols` rather than just the var name.

On your side, I'm not sure exactly what `pytest` is doing, but I notice the callstack mentions assertion rewriting, which, [from descriptions online](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/assert.html), could plausibly introduce new variables. Based on the [last section](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/assert.html#disabling-assert-rewriting) there, you may have some luck running this code using the `--assert=plain` pytest option. Because I don't have a similar environment set up, it's hard for me to take it further than that.